# Parameterising conditional expectation of gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, gaussian-integral

Consider two random variables that are jointly normally distributed: 
$$
(T,C)\sim \text{BiNormal}[(\mu_t,\mu_c),(\sigma_t,\sigma_c),\rho]
$$

I want to express $E[T|C<c^*]$ in terms of the gaussian parameters and the P.D.F and C.D.F of the standard normal.

Below is what I have – Is this correct?

---

1. We know that for the bivariate normal, $E[T|C]=\mu_T + \frac {\sigma_T} {\sigma_C} \rho (C - \mu_C)$
2. Using the law of iterated expectations, we can write 
   $$E[T|C<c^*]=E[E[T|C]|C<c^*]=E[\mu_T + \frac {\sigma_T} {\sigma_C} \rho (C - \mu_C)|C<c^*]$$
3. Taking out of the expectation the constants gives 
   $$\mu_T -\frac {\sigma_T} {\sigma_C} \rho\ \left(\mu_c - E[C|C<c^*]\right)$$
4. And given that $E[C|C<c^*]=\mu_c-\sigma_c\frac{\phi(\frac{c^*-\mu_c}{\sigma_c})}{\Phi(\frac{c^*-\mu_c}{\sigma_c})}$, we finally have
   $$
   \mu_T - \rho\,\sigma_T \, \frac{\phi(\frac{c^*-\mu_c}{\sigma_c})}{\Phi(\frac{c^*-\mu_c}{\sigma_c})}
   $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where your problem was - the approach looks correct to me and I like your method. Here is just another method based on the Cholesky decomposition which arrives with the same answer:

Let $Z_1, Z_2$ be independent standard normal random variables. Then $(T, C)$ has the same distribution as $(\mu_T + \sigma_T(\rho Z_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2), \mu_C+\sigma_CZ_1)$. Therefore,

$$ \begin{align} E[T|C < c^*] 
&= E\left[\mu_T + \sigma_T(\rho Z_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2)
\bigg|\mu_C + \sigma_C Z_1 < c^*\right] \\
&= \mu_T + \sigma_T \rho E\left[ Z_1
\bigg|Z_1 < \frac {c^* - \mu_C} {\sigma_C}\right]
+ \sigma_T\sqrt{1-\rho^2} E\left[Z_2 \bigg|Z_1 < \frac {c^* - \mu_C} {\sigma_C} \right]\\
&= \mu_T - \rho\sigma_T\frac {\displaystyle \phi\left(\frac {c^* - \mu_C} {\sigma_C} \right) } {\displaystyle \Phi\left(\frac {c^* - \mu_C} {\sigma_C}\right)}
\end{align}$$

So you may better check again your numerical answer with your simulation code.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for this. Indeed, the mistake was in the numerical check I was doing (!)

Comment: Would it make sense to edit the OP and post my method as another answer? Or leave method in OP and simply ask for check (which you provide?) Just wondering what might be more helpful for others.