# Parameters for which conditional expectation of non-independent gaussian variables is increasing

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, gaussian-integral

Conside two non-independent gaussian random variables:
$$(,)∼\text{BiNormal}[(,),(,),]$$

I'm interested in understanding when (i.e. for which values of the distribution parameters) it's true that  $$\frac{\partial E[T |C<f(T)+\tau]}{\partial \tau}>0$$
where $f(T)>0$ and $f'(T)>0$ for all $T\in \Bbb R$.

Is there a way to parametrise this conditional expectation, in order to sign the derivative?

---

NOTES:

1. In case it's helpful: I'm actually interested specifically in $f(T)=b*\Phi\left(\frac{T-\mu_a}{\sigma_a}\right)$, where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF of the Standard Normal distribution, and $b\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ is a constant.
2. Here is a relevant approach for a simpler version of this question: [Parameterising conditional expectation of gaussian random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423496/parameterising-conditional-expectation-of-gaussian-random-variables])*
3. I've tried spelling out the expectation via integrals over the joint distribution, and then taking derivatives in Mathematica. This approach was unsuccessful and I posted about it here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222708/derivative-for-conditional-expectation-of-non-independent-gaussian-variables-is